# How to change name attributes for input fields in NodeJS, Express, Passport?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I have two fields for registration:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
```

I want to change name attributes to `usernameReg` and `passwordReg` that I can use for registration using Passport.

```
Account.register(new Account({ username : req.body.username }), req.body.password, function(err, account)
```

I tried changing `req.body.username` to `req.body.usernameReg` and `req.body.password` to `req.body.passwordReg` but it's not working, it's giving me a bad request error (well of course after respectively changing name attributes in HTML)

[Fiddle is here.](https://jsfiddle.net/wjk6fkL1/) - Not full code, just so that it's easier to see with highlighting.

Answer (score 3):

When using passport's `local-strategy` you can pass input fields' names as attributes

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'usernameReg',
  passwordField: 'passwordReg'
  },
  function(username, password, done) {
    Account.register(new Account({ username : username }), password, function(err, account) { .. });
  }
));
```

Then your route would look like:

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
 ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using it also for logging in. I have the same attributes for login fields i.e. name=password and name=username. I'm just trying to avoid having attributes with same names in the same HTML.

Comment: It's nothing wrong to have same names for inputs, as long as they are used in different forms.

Comment: I know, I just want to be on the safe side